# Sorting rectangular contours opencv

Tags: c++, sorting, opencv, image-processing, contour

i have a picture of words , each word is bounded by a rectangular contour. i need the rectangular contour vector to be sorted so i can do some operation on it.

Here is the picture of words(with contours). 
[image with contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjeYh.jpg)

i have tried to sort it and my compare function is

```
bool my_compare(Rect2d rect1, Rect2d rect2)
{  if(((rect1.tl().y) <= rect2.tl().y) &&(rect1.tl().y < rect2.br().y)) 
     return (rect1.tl().x < rect2.tl().x);
  return (rect1.tl().y < rect2.tl().y);
}
```

also i tried this

```
 if((rect1.tl().y == rect2.tl().y))
   return (rect1.tl().x < rect2.tl().x); 
   return (rect1.tl().y < rect2.tl().y);
```

the result is not sorted properly (it doesnt start from very top left or it starts but it skips a contour in the same line ).

Comment: it has worked by the thresholding method , & i thought of doing it your way but ..i believed it could be done in more simple way than that, anyway thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is probably because rectangles in the same row has different height. Let's say a rectangle is followed by a taller rectangle in the same row, the taller rectangle is going to be sorted earlier than the left one.

```
+--------------> x
|          ****           
| ****     *  *
| *  *     *  *
| ****     ****
| rect1    rect2
v
y
```

Using your first compare function, `rect1.tl().y <= rect2.tl().y` is false and `rect1.tl().y < rect2.br().y)` is true, thus return `(rect1.tl().y < rect2.tl().y)` which will put the right rectangle smaller than the left one

One suggestion to overcome this is if the rectangles top left corner difference in y is within a threshold, consider them to be on the same row and compare by x instead.

```
bool my_compare(Rect2d rect1, Rect2d rect2)
{   
    if (fabs(rect1.tl().y - rect2.tl().y) < threshold) 
        return (rect1.tl().x < rect2.tl().x);
    return (rect1.tl().y < rect2.tl().y);
}
```

`fabs` is the floating point absolute function under `<cmath>`. One way to calculate threshold is by using average height of the rectangle.

```
threshold = ((rect1.br().y - rect1.tl().y) + (rect2.br().y - rect2.tl().y)) / 2 * K;
```

K is a constant which you can experiment to see which perform best, it should be between 0 and 1.

Comment: yes ,i tried to handle it using "buttom right point  (br.() )"  in my first code ,this line : if ((( rect1.tl().y) <= rect2.tl().y  ) &&( rect1.tl().y < rect2.br().y )) , it handles the different height problem but still sorts improperly.

Comment: It does not, I have added an example in my answer to illustrate why your first compare fail

Comment: it works the best without k , sometimes it fails unless k = 1